# C# items as root nodes of JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I'm trying to pass a Json that I'd like to access from jquery as,

> jdata.comType

my c# code is,

```
var frontChartList = new List<object>();
frontChartList.Add(new
                {
                    comType = comType,
                    today = DateTime.Now.ToString("D"),
                    agentsAdded = "53",
                    agentsAvail = "47",
                    packageAvailDays = leftDays.ToString(),

                });
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String json = jss.Serialize(frontChartList);
            return json;
```

I cannot access this as

> jdata.comType
>   only as,
>   jdata[0].comType

how should I create the JSON to get a string accessible as jdata.comType?
since I will only be passing one object in this.

Comment: Well, you're deliberately adding it to a list. Why? Why not just serialize the object?

Comment: what json you are getting in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `frontChartList` is a `List<object>`, change it to single object instead:

```
        var frontChartList = new
        {
            comType = comType,
            today = DateTime.Now.ToString("D"),
            agentsAdded = "53",
            agentsAvail = "47",
            packageAvailDays = leftDays.ToString(),

        });
```

Comment: Also, is there a way to initialize the frontChartList object and then assign values to it in if blocks? I get an error saying anonymous type 1 cannot be converted to type 2.

Comment: I think you're better create `public class frontChart { }`, declare its field, then can use var `var frontChartList = new frontChart { };`, after that you can assign values inside `if` block.